# is there any limit of length on creating custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, limit

I am using [custom taxonomy plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/custom-post-type-ui). And I have custom Post type "Product".

When I am creating new taxonomy **"home and garder Appliances Washin"** and attaching it to **Post** or **"Product"** it's not registering with these while If I am adding just **"home and garder Appliances Washi"** and attaching with either **Post or Product** it is working fine.

Is there any length restriction when Creating Custom Taxonomies?

Comment: Okay I got the solution.There is a limit of 32 characters , we can not register more taxonomy whose length is more than 32 characters. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Answer (score 10):

There are some restrictions (caused by lengths of some columns in database).

**Taxonomies**

- Taxonomy name - 32 characters
- Term name (and term slug) - 200 characters

**Posts**

- Post type name - 20 characters
- Post name (slug) - 200 characters
- Meta key - 255 characters

**Options**

- Option name - 64 characters

**Comments**

- Commenter email - 100 characters
- Commenter url - 200 characters
- Comment meta key - 255 characters

**Users**

- User login - 60 characters
- User nicename - 50 characters
- User meta key - 255 characters
- User email - 100 characters
- User url - 100 characters
- User display name - 250 characters

Comment: Taxonomy slugs must be less than 32 characters long.